# AJAX result OK but no data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery to perform following AJAX request:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "url-to-script",
    dataType: "html",
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error:function(){
        showMessage('Chyba', 'error');
    }
});
```

Script that I'm calling is returning part of HTML. It is working properly.
But when I call this AJAX it will end with blank response in data. When I call it again it will return what it should and each next call is working. But the first one after page load is never working. I've no idea why.

I've also tried

```
if (data)
    // do something
else
    try again
```

But it just freeze my browser. So I don't know what is wrong.

Thanks for ideas!

Comment: Check the actual response's content in your browser's console. If it is empty, this is more likely a bug on your server-side code.

Comment: have you put your code under document.ready??

Comment: opening the link directly in the browser returns the code?

Comment: data.d should be your data

Comment: `async: false,` is it necessary?

Comment: @DholakiyaAnkit: It will be data.d only if they are passing a property named "d" from the source :)

Comment: ok is that i did not knew about this

Comment: @dholakiyaAnkit and also if the response is a `json` object.

Comment: Examine the HTTP request and response in your browser's developer tools' Net tab. Are they as you expect? Does the response have a body?

Comment: This code is in function and it's called by click event on some button. It should append returned html to some div but it always worked after second click. So I've tried console.log to check what is in data variable. And its empty in each first call. HTTP returns 200 - ok. But no data. Async isn't necessary but it will make no difference. Opening link directly will always return correct code. data.d is undefined. Hope that I've answered all.

Comment: I'll probably kill myself cause problem was in javascript variable which was in url as parameter.